# What does "Orient a SQLite database" mean?

Tags: sqlite

In class, we got a code to Orient a SQLite database. I kind of get the code (below), but want to get a conceptual understanding of what "Orient" means.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example3.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=\'table\'') #list all tables therein
print c.fetchall()
c.execute('SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=\'table\' AND name=\'students\'') #list columns in table 'students'
print c.fetchall()
conn.close()
```

Comment: I have never heard of "orienting" a database. Are you sure that's what the instructor said?

Comment: It's actually the heading/title of the section... I might be overthinking it, but usually understanding concepts goes a long way for me.

Comment: Are you sure it's not something like "Orientation to Databases" (i.e., how to orient *you* to thinking about databases)? It would be helpful if you shared the exact wording.  I've been working with various RDBMSes for a long time, and I have never heard of using code to "orient" a database. In fact, the code you posted is just a couple of `SELECT`s - it won't *do* anything to the database.

Comment: Title is "Orient a SQLite database"

The following code shows you how to orient a SQLite database in Python. Essentially, you just need to selectively display two columns from the built-in table sqlite_master.

Comment: Well, that's not really a concept, at least as far as I can tell (and Google has only 2 hits for "orient a database"). Any chance there's a language barrier issue? That is, is your instructor a native English speaker?

Comment: He's actually not... I wanted to give him the benefit of the doubt, but maybe backfired. Thanks Ed!!

Comment: Glad to help. Best guess is that he means "connect to a database." You might want to check directly with him. Good luck!